# datagrouping integration in highcharts not highstock?

Tags: highcharts

In our API gives data as daily basis(timestamp and value) but we need to display weekly and monthly with rangeselector integration using highcharts not highstock. Please any help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts doesn't have implemented the **dataGrouping** feature. It is available only in Highstock.

However, you can group your data by yourself before chart will be initialized. For example: If you want to process your data to group it, you will need to loop through your daily data, adding each value into a new data array, indexed on month.

To create a custom **rangeselector** you will need to create two arrays of data - one monthly, second weekly and do an update on particular button.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update